# why is the sum equal to 3000000?

Tags: sql

Write an SQL query that will convert the transaction amount to USD (ccy_code = 840)
taking into account the fact that the rates table contains data only for working days. Transactions made at
weekends are calculated at the rate of the last working day before the holiday/day off.
Result: Client, date, amount of transactions in USD.

Table: Transactions

```
Client_id Report_date Txn_amount
123 2017.01.01 50000
```

Table: Rates

```
Report_date Ccy_code CCy_rate
2016.12.30 840 60,58
2017.01.09 840 61,01
```

I have a few questions about the code:

1. Why do we sort in descending order( desk) when we want to take a smaller date
2. why it turns out 3 million, and not 3029000

---

```
SELECT Client_id, Report_date, sum_usd
FROM
(
SELECT 
    Client_id, 
    Transactions.Report_date,
    Transactions.Txn_amount*Rates.Ccy_rate AS sum_usd, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Transactions.Report_date ORDER BY Rates.Report_date DESC) AS ROW_NUM
     FROM Transactions
        JOIN Rates
        ON Rates.Report_date <= Transactions.Report_date
 WHERE Ccy_code = 840 
) AS T
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

Comment: why doesn't it make sense?
by this I do a selection among smaller dates to select a specific date

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t see the ORDER BY in your ROW_NUMBER window spec. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Show the create table statements. Check the type of the Ccy_rate column and make sure you stored the full decimal value and didn't try to insert 60,50, which might have been truncated to (evaluated as) 60 in the calculation.  When handled correctly, the result is as expected (3029000).

Comment: There are no errors, I checked 

CREATE TABLE Transactions
(   
  Client_id INT NOT NULL , 
  Report_date date NOT NULL,
  Txn_amount INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Transactions
VALUES
(
123, '2017-01-01', 50000
)

CREATE TABLE Rates
(
  Report_date date NOT NULL,
  Ccy_code INT   NOT NULL,
  Ccy_rate DECIMAL(4,2)  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Rates
VALUES
(
'2016-12-30', 840, '60,58'
)

INSERT INTO Rates
VALUES
(
'2017-01-09', 840, '61,01'
)

Comment: That's probably the mistake.  Either amount needs to be decimal or your literal value needs to use a decimal point and not a comma.  __Which database are you using?__  Make sure you add all the detail to the question.  No important information should be only in a comment.  The problem is your rate is being evaluated as a whole integer, without the fractional part.